# How to open an opened file in Finder

Tags: finder

Is there a way to open an opened file in Finder? 
E.g. I have an open txt file, working with it and want to quickly open it in Finder. 
Maybe shortcut or any automator script.

Comment: If the file is already opened why are you trying to open it again?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I say that depends on the program you open the file with, but in most programs you can right-click the file name in the top bar, click the containing folder, and a new Finder window will open with the file already selected:

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

It's also worth noting that the little icon in the window title (as shown in @Siguza's picture) can be used for lots of things. Let's say you have a file open in TextEdit, and you want to open it in Word. You can use that little icon. Go to Word and choose File -> Open. Then go to the little icon at the top of the TextEdit window, grab it, and drag it to Word's File->Open dialog box. The File->Open dialog box will jump to that file. Then you just choose OK, and Word will open the file.